# SQLAlchemy order_by returning numbers based on first number instead of the whole number

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by

I'm building a web app using Python and SQLAlchemy.

I'm using the following code to retrieve records.

> yardDB.query.order_by(yardDB.PIT.asc())

It is returning records based on the ascending order in my "PIT" column, but it's not returning it in the way I need it to. (Green highlight in picture below)

*Note, the Seq column is not the same as the green column. Also the green column is hidden, but I unhid it to see how it's returning the records.

[Picture of how it's returning records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkWOz.png)

I need it to simply return the rows like
**1, 2, 3, .... 10, 11, ... 20, 21, ...**

**Edit**: Listing things I've tried with no success.

- Changed my PIT column data type to Integer and String
- Added leading 00's
- Took off ascending order of query being made.

> yardDB.query.order_by(yardDB.PIT)

Comment: It is sorting the values as strings instead of as numbers. Either the column is defined as a text column or an expression is returning a string value.

Comment: @GordThompson I checked the data type it's returning and it's a string. I've changed the database column as a string and integer and I still get the same result. I've tried looking up my issue because it seems like it should be a common one, but I can't seem to find anything. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

This might be late to the party, but i just solved same issue for myself. Other comments were also suggesting I'm sorting a string column, but i was sorting on id, which definitely was not a string column.

> Also confirmed by typing "User.id.type" in console, which returned "Integer()"

Default sorting for SQLAlchemy [by their documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.order_by) is:

```py
q = session.query(Entity).order_by(Entity.id)
```

What we need to do is to cast the response as decimal

```py
import sqlalchemy as sqla

formated_column = sqla.cast(sqla.func.substring(Entity.id, "([0-9]+)"), sqla.DECIMAL)
q = session.query(Entity).order_by(formated_column)
```

Which sould now return sorted results

- from : 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 2, 21, 22, 23...
- to: 1, 2, 10, 11, 21, 22, 23, 100, 101

> P.S. if you are worried about the performance of the CAST function, it should outperform any other [server functions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3018/performance-comparison-of-the-sql-server-parse-cast-convert-and-tryparse-trycast-tryconvert-functions/)

Comment: Are you sure that the SQLAlchemy type matches the type in the database?  The only way I could reproduce this was if I created `id` as a string type, and changed the SQLA type to integer _after_ rows had been inserted.